# Factory object breaking my Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

The following Capybara test...

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Sheet owner' do
  scenario 'logs in, finds sheet and adds a row' do
    sheet = create :sheet
    user = create :user
    visit login_path
    fill_in('Email', :with => user.email)
    fill_in('Password', :with => user.password)
    click_button('Log in')
  end
end
```

... results in an error:

```
Failures:

1) Sheet owner logs in, finds sheet and adds a row
    Failure/Error: click_button('Log in')
    ActionView::Template::Error:
      no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

Yet passes when I remove `sheet = create :sheet`.

My sheet factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :sheet do
    organization "Organization"
    event "Event"
    description "Description"
    location_id 1
    user_id 1
    misc_dates "1"
  end
end
```

Any ideas why this factory is breaking this test?

In terms of my models, users `has_many` sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are getting an error that prevents click_button from having access to the "Log In" button. It may be looking for it on an error page.

Comment: Good guess but it doesn't look like that is it.  I added back the sheet assignment and then after visiting the login_path confirmed I was there by checking page content.  Also, why wouldn't it have complained about filling in the login fields?